# Loading Panel Contents Dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have developed a template GUI which I wanna reuse and for that purpose I added a panel which is empty in the template and I wanna load things into it dynamically. So assuming the below code:

```
public class TempGUI extends JFrame{

      public TempGUI(JPanel DynamicPanel){
         InitComponents();
         this.DynamicPanel = DynamicPanel;
      }
 ...
}
```

This does not seem to be working as the panel is not changed. I think this should be normal, so is there any way to GET the COMPONENTS of the dynamic panel and SET THEM inside the form ?

Comment: Did you add `DynamicPanel` to the `Container` AFTER you assigned it?  Assigning a panel to another panel doesn't magically add the panel to the container...

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. The forum highlight variable names and method names differently. Follow Java conventions if you expect people to read your code.

Comment: @camickr: you follow any convention you like, I follow my own way. your comment is not answering the question.

Comment: @Arrrr That's why it's a comment.  We follow the [recommend naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) adopted by the majority of professional Java developers around the world, which makes it easier for developers to read the code of others.  You are of course, free to do as you please, but dishing one of the most experienced commentators in this field on the forum is not going to help your cause - just saying

Comment: 1- ,@Arrrr, do you notice how every variable, method and class is highlighted in your code sample? That is because the syntax highlighting of the forum is based on the Java standards. Your code is extremely hard to read because is looks like you are using "static method s and variable everywhere. Again, if you want people to take the time to help, then you take the time to make the read readable and the question meaningful.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: You said Convention, so as different regions of the world may have different cultures and ethics and different people may have different attitudes, those conventions do not apply to me. Actually I hate the camelCase thing.

Comment: @camickr: Show me the highlighted method.

Comment: @Arrrr That's why we have an agreed convention or protocol, to over come these differences.  We could argue this till the cows come home, but generally speaking, you won't win many friends on the subject - IMHO - It's like language, imagine if we couldn't agree on a common language to talk with each other. It's the same in computing, we have common conventions, protocols and standards which allow the hardware and software to communicate, it's all about commonality for a greater good

Comment: @Arrrr, `InitComponent()` is highlighted, the same as the class name is highlighted, the same as the variable name is highlight. Of course you don't notice the highlighting because every thing is the same. Look a MadPgrammers code were he corrected the variable name and method name to see the difference.

Comment: *"have you tried it? and there is no reason to define the private field here. It won't work"* When you can provide a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, I'm sure we'll have a better opportunity to provide a working solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Please explain to me, for what reason you needed that private field, and how adding the panel AS Component can solve the problem, while all the positions may not even fit inside of the INNER panel? What you explained is just (sorry to say that) as joke. If you said use reflection (another silly solution) I'd say no but thank you, but do not try to convince me that your solution would work in any case.

Comment: *"Please explain to me, for what reason you needed that private field"* Why  should it be anything else?  Why would any one else need the ability to access the field directly?  This is just an example of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)

Comment: Please delete your `" you follow any convention you like, I follow my own way. your comment is not answering the question."`  comment, and I'll remove my down-vote. His comment was made to help you post code that we can more easily understand which **will** eventually help you get answers to this and future questions. It is important and it matters.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: To me it is not important, and I won't delete it.

Comment: @Arrrr, wow the [top 3 Swing users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers) in the forum have expressed an interest in helping but you have made no effort to follow any suggestion made. Good luck.

Comment: @camickr: Thanks for the advice but who said I gotta do whatever these 3 top swing user tell me to do? and what makes you think these 3 guys are better than I am? (I may actually know less than 1% of the computer science, not claiming that I'm John von Neumann)

Comment: Then you don't care to make it easier for volunteers to help you. Why?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: I personally think if anyone has problem reading a NAME starting with Uppercase letter, that person is a machine not an intelligent human. And the machine has less analytic power (I got Master of Science in A.I don't argue on this with me) than human brain.

Comment: Please understand that it does take a quite a bit of effort to attempt to quickly understand someone else's code, especially if complex, and that often much understanding comes from subconscious pattern recognition, a process that is made much easier by having code that follows the simple rules of the language being used. And I will argue with you. I'm sure we're both intelligent. Not that it matters but I hold a medical degree from what is ranked the number 1 or 2 medical school in the nation.

Comment: @Arrrr, The suggestions are to help get a better answer faster. I still don't understand what your question is about or understand your confusion with the answer given. Mad gave up trying to explain his solution and asked you to provide a "runnable example" so we could better understand the concept. You are the one asking for help, yet seem unwilling to make any effort to make it easy for people to help you. Even in the past your questions have gone unanswered (and down voted) probably indicating unclear questions. So yes I guess the rest of the forum is to blame for the inability to help..

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: You are from Medic background so you do understand that a brain should naturally understand any patter which it did not know before pretty quickly. A machine can't unless being taught. But it all depends on the intellectual power of a person. I can personally drive both on the left side and the right side, this means that I can adopts to different situations. I can learn them and recall them back. But what you claimed (people having problem reading my code), this behavior is closer a machine's behavior. Our brain IS NOT MEANT TO follow rules to process things.

Comment: `people having problem reading my code` yes, because we make assumptions about the code based on the Java conventions. `SomeWord.doSomething(...)`. Looking at that single line of code without the context of the rest of a program. Is "doSomething" a static method or a class method? Using Java conventions we can tell you immediately. Using your conventions we have no idea, and need to spend more time analysing the rest of the code. This is not an efficient use of our time.

Comment: @camickr: Well, Java is one of the language that I know, I also do C# a lot more than Java same as Python or C++. But I also know VB very well, and VB does not care about upper case lower case. so if you have (Dim User = "Test", then you can't have Dim user = "" in the same context). How do you deal what that situation then?

Comment: @Arrrr, Each language has its own conventions. It you want to program in multiple languages and converse with other programmers in those languages then you should use the conventions of the language. I don't know the other languages so I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

All `this.DynamicPanel = DynamicPanel;` is make the instance field, `this.DynamicPanel` now point to what ever the parameter `DynamicPanel` is.  If the parameter is not on the screen in anyway, then you will no see anything.  In fact, this will not affect what ever `this.DynamicPanel` was pointing to.

Instead, consider actually adding the parameter to the container...

```
public class TempGUI extends JFrame{

      public TempGUI(JPanel DynamicPanel){
         InitComponents();
         this.DynamicPanel.add(DynamicPanel);
      }
 ...
}
```

But then you'd need to change things around a bit, so you would have `DynamicPanelContent` (which would replace `this.DynamicPanel`), this would allow you to continue to reference `this.DynamicPanel` which would point to what ever you passed to the constructor...

```
public class TempGUI extends JFrame{

      private JPanel dynamicPanel;

      public TempGUI(JPanel dynamicPanel){
         initComponents();
         this.dynamicPanel = dynamicPanel;
         this.dynamicPanelContent.add(this.dynamicPanel);
      }
 ...
}
```

Or some such...

**Updated with example**

> have you tried it? and there is no reason to define the private field here. It won't work.

Seems to work fine for me...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel myView = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello!");
                myView.add(label, gbc);
                JButton btn = new JButton("Say good-bye");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        label.setText("Good bye");
                    }
                });
                gbc.gridy++;
                myView.add(btn, gbc);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane(myView));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane<V extends JPanel> extends JPanel {

        private V view;

        public TestPane(V view) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.view = view;
            JPanel viewContent = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            viewContent.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            viewContent.add(view);

            add(viewContent);
        }

        public V getView() {
            return view;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If I wanted to do this I'd add a param of type JComponent and would manually arrange the UI and I don't wanna do that.

Comment: @Arrrr Then, please by all means, explain to me, how you hope that assigning one variable to another will magically make your component appear on the screen.  What you want to do and what you can do aren't always the same thing

Comment: And in that case, what happens to the events that I may have inside the panel? I wanna GET things OUT of the To-BE-Loaded panel and SET them inside of the INNER ONE.

Comment: Then, you will need to reassign the event handlers when you assign the new component.  You seem to be misunderstanding how variable assignment works at a basic level.  Your setters would need to use the reference of `dynamicPanel` (which was assigned within the constructor) to set the values you need.

Comment: "this.dynamicPanelContent" what is this?

Comment: It's your `this.DynamicPanel` renamed to so I can still reference the `this.dynamicPanel` and get/set values to/from it

Comment: have you tried it? and there is no reason to define the private field here. It won't work.